# Exception in Application constructor while making a constructor

Tags: javafx

When I am running the below mentioned code it is working

```
import javafx.application.Application;
public class Client {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Test t2 = new Test();
    Application.launch(t2.getClass(),args);
    }
}
```

where the test class is

```
package com.temp.com.serverclient;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.setTitle("No Main");
    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(new Label("It worked!"));
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 120));
    primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

But if I am trying to add constructor,it is getting Exception in Application constructor,Error. 
The code is

```
package com.temp.com.serverclient;

import javafx.application.Application;

public class Client {
public static void main(String[] args){

    Test t1 = new Test("Pass this String to Constructor");
    Application.launch(t1.getClass(),args);
    }
}
```

Test class

```
package com.temp.com.serverclient;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {
String str;
public Test(String str) {
    this.str = str;
}
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.setTitle("No Main");
    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(new Label("It worked!"));
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 120));
    primaryStage.show();
    }
 }
```

How Can I sovle the problem? I need to pass the String to collect information from previous class.

Answer (score 1):

`Application.launch` always uses a `public` parameterless constructor to create a instance of the application class to launch. (It does not provide any benefit to create a instance in the main method BTW. Simply pass the class without creating a instance, i.e. `Application.launch(Test.class, args);`.)

In fact you can only pass `String` parameters to the new instance of your application class without using `static` members and it's done via the `args` parameter of `Application.launch`:

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(Test.class, "Pass this String to Constructor");
    }
}
```

```
public class Test extends Application {

    String str;

    @Override
    public init() {
        this.str = getParameters().getRaw().get(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("No Main");
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(new Label("It worked!"));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 120));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Note that accessing the `parameters` property is also possible for the start method.

---

JavaFX 9 introduced a new possiblility: using `Platform.startup` but you need to handle the lifecycle of the application class yourself:

```
Application app = new Test("Pass this String to Constructor");
app.init();
Platform.startup(() -> {
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    try {
        app.start(stage);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
    }
});
```

This does not properly call the `Application.stop` method though. Also the parameters are not assigned.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, `Application.launch` creates a new instance of `Test`. Therefore, you need another way to get the value to the instance, e. g. using a static getter method in your `Client` class which is called from `Test`